# Looping Google searches with PHP

Tags: php, html, search, fwrite

For an iPhone game I'm writing I have written a PHP script that loops through a CSV file of 50000 words and writes the number of Google results that each particular word returns to a .txt file.

The PHP code is all fine and works... BUT... Google blocked the requests after approx 200 searches out of the 50000 :(

When I echo the response to the page I get - HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable

Can anyone suggest a way of getting around this? Also, what's strange for me is I can search Google in my browser from the same IP address and it returns the results as normal.

Can anyone shine any light on the whole thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Searching google in a browser is fine, google is thinking that your 50000 requests in a couple of seconds is a denial of service attack and is block your requests.

Comment: What you are doing likely violates Google's Terms of Service.

Comment: yeh thought as much. it asked me to enter a captcha when i fired a url in a vm

Answer (score 0):

Google won't let you use its search engine for such a purpose. They allow only 'normal' users to query their search engine.

They seem to have an API you could use, but it's limited to 100 queries a day. For more you must pay 5$ for 1000 queries. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#Pricing